# Слово "ошарашить"

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова "ошарашить"?

Answer (score 1):

Словарь ***Фасмера***:

*Слово:Шарахнуть, Ближайшая этимология: Шарашить, укр. Шарахнути "броситься", Шарах! -- межд., блр. Шарахнуць "рвануть, резануть". По-видимому, звукоподражательное; см. Преобр., Труды I, 88; Горяев, ЭС 418; Ильинский, ИОРЯС 20, 4, 173. Сравнивают с Шаркать, Шорох, Шуршать, даже с Швырять. 
Слово:Шарашь Ближайшая этимология: Ж. "первый лед на реке", Шерошь, Шарошь, Шарш -- то же, поволжск. (Даль). Вероятно, связано с предыдущим; см. Ильинский, ИОРЯС 20, 4, 173.*

Вероятно, слово "ошарашить" образовалось от "шарашить" с помощью приставки о-. 
Словарь ***Ожегова*** так толкует это слово:"*ОШАРАШИТЬ —  кого (что). 1. Сильно ударить (прост.). О. палкой. 2. перен. Озадачить, поставить в тупик (разг.). О. вопросом. "* Прослеживается смысловая связь с "шарашить", "шарахнуть".

Answer (score 0):

Как ни удивительно, но слово ***ошарашить*** (от *шарашить*) родственно словам *заразить, поразить*. В чешском языке: *ошарашенный* = **zaražený** от глагола *zarazit* = *поразить, забить, вбить*.

Словарь Даля: ***ЗАРАЖАТЬ***, заразить кого чем, стар. поражать, убивать, разить на смерть: ныне: сообщать невидимо яд, что-либо вредное, губительное, особ. наносную болезнь.